# Getting 308 - Permanent Redirection issue while running rest assured script with java

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, postman, rest-assured

I'm trying to run the APIs using RestAssured with Java and getting the below exception.

```
Caught Exception :sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Where as, when I hit the same API thru Postman, it is giving the valid response.

**FYI -** The API URL is configured in CA Layer7 and i have added headers like API Key and Secret Key in **Postman**

```
RestAssured.baseURI = Config.getConfigs().getPropertyValue("baseURL");
requestSpec = RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation();

HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("x-clientsecret", "xxxx");
headers.put("x-apikey", "xxxx");
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
requestSpec.headers(headers);
```

After tried with the below method, it is giving **308 - Permanent Redirection** exception.

```
requestSpec = RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation();
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<308> but was:<200>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
```

Anyone provide your suggestions/solutions for that issue?

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: did you try to add the same headers to restAssured as well?

Comment: Yes Marek, I have updated the post as well FYR.